# How do I set up FTP automount with a timeout?

Tags: ftp, automount

I need to automount ftp, but not only at boot but always with some timeout. This ftp server is mediaplayer.

Like USB but FTP.

The mountpoint should be available to all users.

Ubuntu version 14.04.

I use:

```
curlftpfs#root:12345@192.168.1.226 /media/MediaPlayer fuse rw,uid=1000,umask=0777,user,suid,allow_other,exec,auto,utf8  0   1
```

but it does not allow me to write anywhere. It shows in nautilus, but no write access. Tried all in `mnt` and `/usr/share` `/usr/local/share`.

I found a writable folder, `/media/MediaPlayer/mnt/usbmounts/sda3` but every time I write it says: unable to change owner.

Comment: I'm looking at WiFi FTP Server on Android to allow access from Ubuntu and I'm curious how this all turned out for you?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You should find free ftp server for android first, then use it as usual, may be configuring dns/dhcp on router also. I don't interested in question anymore as not using android on my mediaplaers anymore but use libreelec instead of it. I don't remember how above problem was solved.

Comment: I was thinking FTP server first because it has 1 million installs but it seems not be updated anymore? WiFi FTP server has 500K installs and is higher rated. Here's my problem I'm working on if you are interested: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178818/how-to-mount-android-external-storage-over-wifi-instead-of-usb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use Autofs. Here is a good documentation/tutorial about it : [Autofs - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs)

And here you'll find how to use it with FTP : [Autofs | FTP and SSH (with FUSE) - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs#FTP_and_SSH_.28with_FUSE.29)

the Timeout setting at the master file level is the timeout before automatic disconnection after a period of inactivity.

Warning : FTP is very light to be used like a regular File System. You can have some bad performance due to the FTP protocol design. If you can do it, prefer ssh/scp with certificate authentication.

Best regards,

Comment: Following the instructions in your link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs#FTP_and_SSH_(with_FUSE) works fine. Except with one change: `mountpoint -fstype=curl,user=USER:PASSWORD,allow_other,disable eprt :ftp\://ftp.xxxx.xx`